# misbehavior of javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a piece of JavaScript(jquery) code in my body area. Assume the code is

```
$(".count_input").on("change",function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

But it doesn't word. I want this code to alert me when I make changes in my inputs.

The code syntax and algorithm is true, because it works when I implant it with chrome's console;

I have to add that my script tag is like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            /**********************
            this part doesn't work
            **********************/
            $(".count_input").on("change",function(){
                alert("hi");
            });
            /*************************************************************/
            /**************
            this part works
            **************/
        $.get("../files/cart.php",{action:'main_cart'},function(data) {
            data = data.split("dbseperatordb");
            $(".cart_count").html("");
            $(".main_cart_html").html("");
            $("#total_price").html("0");
            var main_cart_html = data[0];
            var total_price = data[1];
            $(".main_cart_html").html(main_cart_html);
            $(".total_price").html(total_price);

        });
        /****************************************************************/
    })
</script>
```

here is the HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="cart_img pull-left width-100 padding-10 text-left">
        <img src="../products/h1/images/1.jpg" alt="" width="80">
    </div>
    <a href="../pages/single-item.php?id=1" class="product_name">
        <span>عسل</span>
        <small>&#65279;کمی توضیحات<br>معمولاً طراحان گرافیک برای صفحه&zwnj;آرایی�</small>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="remove_item">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="total_price">342000</div>
    <div class="qty">
    <input type="number" value="4" class="count_input" id="1input_count" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1">
 × 90000 ريال</div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could it be the extra closing bracket on the line after `alert("hi")` ?

Comment: What inputs? Are you adding them with  `$(".main_cart_html").html(main_cart_html);`? i.e. after you've searched for them and bound the event handlers?

Comment: Inputs exist in page, the second part of cod is for example which does work but the first part doesnt.

Comment: Can you show the HTML near .count_input?

Comment: What type of element exactly is `.count_input`? I have a suspicion that you're misunderstanding what kinds of events will trigger a `change`.

Comment: @NickZ — Since it works via the console, it sounds like a timing issue.

Comment: I tried it in above, between and bottom of my code and even near other codes that are working with no problem(like here in my question), but the problem still exists.

Comment: @MahyarJafari — Edit the question to add more information. Don't make people try to read code from the comments.

Comment: Where does `main_cart_html` come into it? Does removing the `$.get()` call from your code fix the problem?

Comment: guys, the second part of code which has ajax in it, works and I used that here to show you the first part doesn't work even, I don't have any problem with the code and I want to just get alert when I change the input. note that the code works with chrome's console.

Comment: it is working. how you reference your js? external file?

Comment: It's near other html elements including <input class="count_input"  ....>

Comment: @MahyarJafari — "second part of code which has ajax in it, works"  — Yes, but as I asked earlier, have you tried removing it to see if it is interfering with the first chunk of code that you say doesn't work.

Comment: @Quentin some html elements including those inputs are gathered by that $.get() code from a php file and if I remove that, I dont have any inputs to call to.

Comment: @MahyarJafari — That's a very important fact that you should have mentioned in the first place. And again when I asked *Are you adding them with `$(".main_cart_html").html(main_cart_html);`?* !

Comment: @Quentin so do I have to bring the script from that php file to be after input elements?

Answer (score 2):

> some html elements including those inputs are gathered by that $.get() code

This is what your code does:

1. Bind an event handler to all `.count_input` elements *currently* in the document
2. Make an HTTP request
3. With the response to that HTTP request, add some `.count_input` elements

Since the elements you add in step 3 don't exist at step 1, they never get event handlers bound to them.

Move the code which binds the event handlers to the end of the function you pass to `$.get`

Comment: I requested the script from that php file after other elements and the problem finally solved. Thanks for your help bro.

Answer (score 0):

> I want this code to alert me when I make changes in my inputs.

The `change` event is not fired until the input element's value is committed by the user. The user must first input a new value and then blur the input element, by tabbing to another form element or clicking outside the input element, to actually commit the change. Not until then would the `change` event fire.

You can use the `input` event instead, which is fired synchronously when the value of an input element is changed.

The `input` event is not supported on legacy browsers (IE<9) though. For supporting those you might want to consider listening to `keyup`/`keydown` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that wasn't the problem.